# Choose FBA users from Windows Site

Tags: forms-authentication, extranet

We have configured our Extranet site to work with Active Directory user authentication with a Windows Authenticated and extended Forms-Based Authenticated site.

We can configure FBA users on the FBA site fine, but unfortunately we can't configure FBA users from the Windows site. We try prefixing the username with membership:[username] but this doesn't work. (I've confirmed the prefix is "membership"). Is there a way to be able to pick FBA users from the Windows auth site? To be clear, we don't want to enable dual-authentication with the Windows site (i.e. where you can specify how to login).

I'm wondering if this is maybe a People Picker issue?

Answer (score 1):

Peter,

Unfortunately, you have no choice but to enable dual authentication on the Windows-only zone as well if you want Windows users to be able to find FBA users through the people picker as this is a limitation of SharePoint (the People Picker can only pick users from the underlying, enabled authentication types).

If the issue is simply that you don't want Windows users to be prompted to sign in on the site, note that you can configure auto sign in for Windows users when they are inside the corporate network (and you know which IP addresses their machines are assigned to) by using OrbitOne's auto sign in feature (https://spautomaticsignin.codeplex.com/).

This auto sign in feature is also available (with a UI, not just a PowerShell command) in Extradium, the FBA product my company sells (http://www.extradium.com).

Comment: Thanks Raphael - for some reason when I've worked with SharePoint 2007 and 2010, I thought it was possible. (Pre-Claims).

Comment: As far as I remember, that was the same behavior in SharePoint 2007 and 2010, but I might be wrong.

On a related note, we've done some extensive work in Extradium to filter the users you can see in the People Picker depending on who you are. For instance, external users may only see Windows users on the current site, while Windows users can see all other Windows users. Conversely, you can limit which external users other external users can see (based on their organization) while Windows users can see them all. In a nutshell, it's much more flexible than the OOTB SharePoint experience.